# How always to force a specific date format in inserted cell?

Tags: excel, date, vba

When I am inserting a new date-like value in an Excel cell using VBA the date format is never consistent and correct.

How can I change that cell's date formatting and make sure the inserted value is a real date and not a string representation of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **solution**:

First of all if you want to be sure that the value you are inserting is indeed a date make a simple test:

```
    If IsDate(valueToInsert) Then
```

Then change the actual number format of the cell you want to insert in your worksheet (WS):

```
    WS.Range(WS.Cells(row, col).Address).NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" 'for example
```

All you need to do now is insert the value correctly in the cell you formatted above:

```
     WS.Cells(row, col) = CDate(Format(valueToInsert, "dd/MM/yyyy")) 'same dateformat
```

Below is the complete solution.

```
    If IsDate(valueToInsert) Then
        WS.Range(WS.Cells(row, col).Address).NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        WS.Cells(row, col) = CDate(Format(valueToInsert, "dd/MM/yyyy"))
    Else
        WS.Cells(row, col) = valueToInsert
    End If
```

I hope this can help to someone as it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the number format of the range.

```
Sheet1.Range("A2").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Then format the data going in.

```
szDate = "1/1/2001"
Sheet1.Range("A2").Valeu = Format(szDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

To the get the exact format you want you can record a macro while you set one through the right click -> format tools.

Comment: Hello MatthewD thank you for the quick reply. This was how I previously had it coded but it did not work. I had to do an additional step and actually convert the szDate to a Date using CDate.

Comment: You could try declaring it as a date.  Dim dDate as Date.  That might save the convert.